# Is pipe ( | ) a command?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, pipe

As I understand it, pipe `( | )`  takes the standard output of one process and passes it as standard input into another process.

But I want to know if pipe `( | )` is considered a command like ls, grep etc.

How many commands are in command line below?

`ls /etc | grep nginx`

I'm confused if I should count the pipe `( | )`

Comment: Pipe is an operator, not a command.

Comment: If it was a command, you would be able to run it standalone: `|`. Try.

Comment: How would the shell know where one command starts and another one begins?

Comment: @gronostaj The shell has several well-defined delimiters. You can mess with these by escaping with a backslash but in general hitting a unescaped new-line, a semi-colon, or a pipe signals the end of a command. Backgrounding the command with `&` will also work in many circumstances.

Comment: @doneal24 I understand that, but I'm trying to show OP how they could have tried to figure this out themselves. `&` being an ordinary command would make parsing tricky and somewhat arbitrary, which suggests it's maybe not the approach that designers would choose

Comment: @gronostaj: That sounds logical, until you consider `[`. `bash` carries half a century of ad-hoc decisions, many made before we knew better.

Comment: @MSalters Can you explain how `[` changes my reasoning? I don't think there are any exceptions where `[` would be accepted but not a command with a more usual name.

Comment: @gronostaj : It would appear like UNIX chose to use letters for commands and symbols for operators, escaping, and the like. `[` seems to be the one exception, with the weird convention that the "matching" `]` is not matched at all by the shell, but eaten as an argument by the `[` command.

Comment: @MSalters You're right, but I don't think this breaks my train of thought. If `|` was a command like `[`, it would still be unclear how the command splitting is supposed to be done.

Comment: if pipe was a command, you'd find it under /usr/bin or generally in any /bin folder (for binarys) - because *commands* are *programs* , but not every *program* is a *command* . [plus, there is stuff like functions or alias but these are not technically commands i guess]

Comment: @clockw0rk if someone was asking if `[` is a command, would you say it is not, because we can't find it in `*/bin/`? ;)

Comment: @PierU Actually you can: `/usr/bin/[`

Comment: @clockw0rk I'd say that if anything, it's the other way around: every program is (potentially) a command, but not every command is a program. When you execute the `echo` command, you're actually calling shell's built-in, not the `echo` program from $PATH, so clearly not every command is a program (even if a corresponding program exists, which is not a necessity). I guess one could also argue that commands and programs are two different things: command is the thing you type, program is what gets executed. I wonder if POSIX has anything to say about it.

Comment: @gronostaj ooops... my bad, I never noticed that !

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In Bash a pipe (`|` along with `|&`) is not a command, rather it is a control operator.

From [this reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html):

> A pipeline is a sequence of one or more commands separated by one of
> the control operators ‘|’ or ‘|&’.

So in the context of your example, `ls` and `grep` would be the commands and you should not include the pipe.

Comment: `ls` is a command-line tool on par with `grep`. It is not a shell built-in. Both programs live in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`. There is considerable discussion on using `type` vs. `which` vs. `command -v` vs `whence` vs. a half-dozen other commands but some of these commands will tell you when a command is a shell built-in, when they are aliases, and when they are programs in `/bin`. The `type` command might be the best bet here. Compare `type ls` with `type [[`.

Comment: Ok, great to know.  Thanks for clarifying that, I've removed that bit from my answer.

Comment: You can get into difficulties when both `test` and `echo` are both shell built-in's on most shells and both exist in `/usr/bin` and they have different options/outputs depending on how you call them. Even worse, invoking `/usr/bin/cd` will change your directory for the duration of the command but the shell's cwd is not changed. The built-in `cd` will change the directory for the shell. Blame POSIX for requiring the existence of `/usr/bin/cd`. FYI, `compgen -b` will show all the shell built-ins on any POSIX-compliant shell.

Comment: @squillman A simple command is ["a sequence of optional variable assignments and redirections, in any sequence, optionally followed by words and redirections, terminated by a control operator."](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01) Something  `LC_ALL=C grep '^[a-z]' < somefile`, or indeed the `ls /etc` and `grep nginx` above are simple commands, but things like `if`, `while` constructs as well as `{ ...; }` and `( ... )` blocks are compound commands instead.

Comment: @ilkkachu Ah, also good to know.  Thanks!

Comment: @doneal24 `/usr/bin/[` is a fun one to blow some minds.

Comment: @doneal24 "`compgen -b` will show all the shell built-ins on any POSIX-compliant shell" – On any? I doubt it. AFAIK `compgen` is not specified by POSIX.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks for the comment. I had thought that `compgen` was POSIX but I seem to be mistaken. Take it a bashism instead.

Comment: Not just a bashism, but a bashism that's only present when the shell is compiled with interactive extensions enabled. If you're on NixOS, f/e, the `bash` package has no `compgen`; one needs `bashInteractive` for it to be available.

Comment: Really dumb question – what's the difference between `|` (which I know and love) and `|&` (which I've just seen here)?

Comment: @Landak GNU Bash manual -> [3.2.2 Pipelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html): _"If `|&` is used, `command1`’s standard error, in addition to its standard output, is connected to `command2`’s standard input through the pipe; it is shorthand for `2>&1 |`. This implicit redirection of the standard error to the standard output is performed after any redirections specified by `command1`."_

Answer (score 4):

The proof is in actual testing. In bash:

```
|
```

returns:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
```

while:

```
a|b
```

where a and b are unknown commands, returns:

```
-bash: b: command not found
-bash: a: command not found
```

with no reference to | because the pipe is perfectly fine when used between any two arbitrary commands, the problem is that these commands do not exist.

I suspect "b: command not found" comes first because in order the receiver (b) has to be running before the sender (a). If they were started (a) then (b), if (b) took longer to start up than (a) took to start sending, the data would have no place to go.

Comment: On my system (WSL Ubuntu) the `command not found` messages are outputted in random order, which probably means that both processes are launched at (almost) same time.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answer: the pipe operator tells the shell that the two commands should be organized in a pipeline, as in the flow of text from one to the other. For that, the shell creates an anonymous pipe, i.e. a FIFO file-like channel, by calling the kernel. Then the shell runs the two commands, passing the input of the pipe to the first command as its stdout file descriptor, and the output of the pipe to the second command as its stdin. So text goes from stdout of the first command to stdin of the second one via the pipe.

If the pipe symbol denoted a separate command, that program would need to get hold of the processes of the other two commands somehow, then pass file descriptors for the anonymous pipe to them (assuming this is possible between processes that aren't parent and child), and those programs would need to swap their stdout and stdin with these descriptors, when they're already running—under the danger of potential loss of output in the meantime. This all is rather easier accomplished by the shell, which already knows the two processes, has special parent relationship with them, and can supply the file descriptors right at the start.